# Where can I post a job listing to outsource a graphic design project?

Tags: business, hiring

I'm on the stage of hiring a graphic designer for my Android app and I was thinking that it will be a better idea to hire the right person for this task. I know about websites as elance, odesk, etc that have sections for graphical design jobs.

Are there any other sites on which to post a graphical designer job?

Comment: freelanceswitch.com comes to mind.

Comment: GRAPHIC design. Not GRAPHICAL. We Graphic Designers cringe at that. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The one place you'll find some of the most incredible designers: http://www.dribbble.com

Comment: Dribbble is definitely a great place to find the best mobile designers. There’s a “Hire Me” button for designers who are available.

Answer (score 4):

I do use freelancer.com quite a bit, but have used them for web development mainly. I am considering using them for graphic design as well. Do think a cultural connection is more important here so would go for a designer connected to the culture/background of the client. Different cultures tend to produce different styles and these styles might by too loud or too quiet in once culture/country and vice versa in another.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend staff.com. They have a list of talented graphic designers at guaranteed low costs. Hire them for a trial period and if you are satisfied with their results, you can hire them full time. That's what I did with my web developer now. Staff.com is free, they work just like odesk.com. Check on this link: https://www.staff.com/search/graphic%20designer/1

Comment: $6 an hour!? Just be prepared to get what you pay for, I guess.

Answer (score -3):

http://community.zipboard.co/t/elearning-job-board/77/1 is a very good source, of freelance graphics designer and the company who need to post the graphics work free and globally.