# Very Basic Question I really Need Help With

Tags: paper

Like I said, basic....

I have a series of simple illustrations and graphs on physical paper.

Now I need those graphs/ images made to look professional digitally for worksheets, books, online, etc.

Who do I take the physical sheets of paper to and how do I get a hold of such people?

I have some pressing deadlines.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hire a graphic designer?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/how-to-hire-a-graphic-designer) or [Where can I post a job listing to outsource a graphic design project?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/where-can-i-post-a-job-listing-to-outsource-a-graphic-design-project)

Answer (score 0):

Scan them and post them to freelancing sites like [upwork.com](http://www.upwork,com), [freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com), [guru.com](http://www.guru.com), or numerous photoshop forums. There you can post your requirements as jobs for a fixed price or on an hourly basis. Freelancing graphic designers can bid on the jobs and help you finish your job. Its a very cost effective way and you can get very many quality designers.